# How to remove new line using linux command

Tags: linux

I have a file that contains data as follows:

```
text1, text2, text3,
text4
text5, text6, text7,
text8
```

I need to bring the text4, text8 to the previous line that ends with a comma. How can I achieve this please ?

**EDIT:** Please, note that I have thousands of line. I need to automate the process.

Comment: You did not specify what language you want to use, my guess would be bash (bashscript)?

Comment: @Cthulhu: I am not a linux user but I had to use it now. Can you write the command as I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @burninggramma: Yes bash would be fine. Any thing that does the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `perl` command:

```
$ perl -p -e 's/,\n/, /g' file
text1, text2, text3, text4
text5, text6, text7, text8
```

Comment: All if the posted solutions should be fine, just give Perl more file names on the command line, or write a shell loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
> perl -pe 'if(/,\n/){$_=~s/\n//g}' temp
text1, text2, text3,text4
text5, text6, text7,text8
```

do it inplace :

```
perl -pi -e 'if(/,\n/){$_=~s/\n//g}' temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl is probably the easiest tool:

```
perl -wpe 'chomp if /,$/' file
```

This says: Print all the lines of "file", but leave out the newline if the line ends on a comma.